# Progress bar with non-changing line above (in R)

Tags: r, console, flush

I would like to give a little informative message about where I am in the for-loop.
So I have this snippet of code:

```
for (i in 1:20) {
 dashes = paste0(replicate(20, "-"), collapse = "") 
 cat("This should be above and not change")
 cat(paste0("\r", i, " ", dashes)) 
 Sys.sleep(0.3)
}
```

However, the output in the console looks like this:

```
9 --------------------This should be above and not change
```

While the number updates in place (which is the behavior I wanted), the "This should...", should be placed above and not move at all. I tried a couple of things but did not really succeed in doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Not a very good question...

This simple `if` does the trick.

```
for (i in 1:20) {
 dashes = paste0(replicate(20, "-"), collapse = "") 
 if (i == 1) {
   cat("This should be above and not change\n")
 }
 cat(paste0("\r", i, " ", dashes)) 
 Sys.sleep(0.3)
}
```